# How does one do a model query from other model function?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following classes: Student, LabJournal, JournalResponse, and JournalField. I want to define a "status" function for student to determine how many questions (JournalField) they've answered (JournalResponse). The problem is the function dies without a return on the following line:

```
total_questions = models.JournalResponse.objects.filter(owner__exact=self.id).filter(field__journal__exact=self.assignment).count()
```

My guess is that I'm doing the model query wrong from within the class definition, or that you're not allowed to query from within a separate model. However I have not found anything in the docs to confirm or deny this, and without any errors it's difficult to debug. Running Django 1.1.

Code below:

```
class Student (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, null=False, related_name='student')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, related_name='students')
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(LabJournal, blank=True, null=True, related_name='students')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/labjournal/student/%i/" % self.id

    def status(self):
        if self.assignment == None : return "unassigned"
        percent_done = 0
        total_questions = models.JournalResponse.objects.filter(owner__exact=self.id).filter(field__journal__exact=self.assignment).count()
        answered_questions = models.JournalResponse.objects.filter(owner__exact=self.id).filter(field__journal__exact=self.assignment).filter(text!=None).count()
        percent_done = (answered_questions/total_questions)*100
        return '%d%% done' % percent_done

class JournalResponse (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=False, related_name='responses')
    field = models.ForeignKey(JournalField, null=False, related_name='responses')
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    file = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)


class JournalField (models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (u'HTML', u'HTML'),
        (u'IF', u'ImageField'),
        (u'TF', u'TextField'),
    )

    journal = models.ForeignKey(LabJournal, null=False, related_name='fields', help_text='Parent Journal')
    ordinal = models.IntegerField(help_text='Field order')
    type = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, help_text='Field type')
    # Contains HTML content for HTML fields, contains the text marked "question" closest
    # to and above the current field for picture and text entry fields
    content = models.TextField(help_text='Should contain HTML content for HTML (question) fields or associated (previous question) HTML for ImageFields and TextFields.')
```

**UPDATED**
Here's the working status method:

```
def status(self):
    if self.assignment == None : return "unassigned"
    percent_done = 0
    # sets up query, but doesn't actually hit database
    response_set = self.responses.filter(owner=self).filter(field__journal=self.assignment)
    # force float so divide returns float
    # the two count statements are the only two actual hits on the database
    total_questions = float(response_set.count())
    answered_questions = float(response_set.exclude(text='').count())
    percent_done = (answered_questions/total_questions)*100
    return '%d%% done' % percent_done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to `models.JournalResponse` which shouldn't exist (AttributeError?) because in the class definition the same `models` name is referring to `django.db.models`

You would need to refer to it via the actual model object, so `JournalResponse.objects.filter()`.

In your case, you have a reverse relationship to `JournalResponse` from `Student` so you can simply use `self.journalresponse_set.filter()` to access `JournalResponse.objects.filter(student=self)`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Try:

```
self.journalresponse_set.filter(field__journal=self.assignment)
```

Also, your next filter line would break as well on `text!=None`. Use `exclude(text=None)` syntax instead.

Comment: The problem is that no error is thrown. Hence my issues debugging.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! Yeah, it's very odd that the line `models.JournalResponse` doesn't throw an `AttributeError` right away. I'd put `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` inside the `status` definition and start running your exact query. You could try going straight to my suggestion and seeing if it works as well.

Comment: pdb to the rescue, thanks! The problem was an import statement: `from django.contrib.gis.db import models` which overloaded the models class call. after I removed the `models.` from the offending lines the original code worked. Will now try your suggestion for following relationship backwards.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling `self.journalresponse_set.all()` gives the error "AttributeError: "'Student' object has no attribute 'journalresponse_set'"". So reverse relationship invocation seems not to work for some reason...

Comment: Ah, I see. `journalresponse_set` is merely the default name django provides if you don't override it with `related_name`, which you've done, so it would be `self.responses.filter(...)`